# Generate my links automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to generate my links automatically via a static class in each of my aspx pages (or in a common BasePage).

Currently I use this:

```
private const string TEMPLATE =
    "~/One.aspx";

public static string Link ()
(
    string link = String.Format(TEMPLATE);
    return link;
)
```

But the name of my page, One.aspx is hardcoded. Is it possible to generate the path instead of this hardcoded constant TEMPLATE. You should know that I do not instantiate the class before creating the link.

The idea is to never hardcode a link but use a variable in my Redirect()

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(PageOne.Link);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a T4 script which generates the desired class according to project structure and filenames.